# Python sequence error

Tags: python, numpy

I have written a code to solve various integrals using the midpoint method. I had it working for some other functions, however when trying to compute this particular function's integral (you will see it within the code), I am running into this error: "setting an array element with a sequence." If someone could point out what is causing this issue, it would be much appreciated.

Edit: I have marked the line where the error is occurring.

Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *


N = 1000
xi = 1.0
xf = 4.0
dx = (xf - xi)/N
x = zeros(N+1)
F = zeros(N+1)
k = m = 1
Z = 2*sqrt((2*m)/2)
A = 1
x[0] = xi
F[0] = 0.0
for i in range(1,N+1):
    x[i] = x[i-1] + dx
    xmid = (x[i] + x[i-1])/2.0
    F[i] = F[i-1] + dx*(Z*sqrt(k*A**4 - k*x**4)) #error here
print 'F at', xf, ' = ', F[N]
plot(F,x,'b')
xlabel('F')
ylabel('x')
show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At runtime on the first iteration of the loop the problematic line has the addition of an array and a scalar which broadcast to a array:

```
F[i-1] = 0.0
dx*(Z*sqrt(k*A**4 - k*x**4)) = array([ 0.   ,    nan,  0.006, ...,  0.006,  0.006,  0.006])
```

So at runtime it's trying assign an array to the index, which isn't well-defined for the one dimensional `F` array.

```
F[i] = array([ 0.   ,    nan,  0.006, ...,  0.006,  0.006,  0.006])
```

Check your formula, but I'm guessing you probably intended to do something like this instead:

```
dx*(Z*sqrt(k*A**4 - k*x[i]**4))
```

Comment: I always make such silly oversights. I shouldn't try to program so late. This fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `x` is a array.  So,

```
F[i-1] + dx*(Z*sqrt(k*A**4 - k*x**4))
```

return *an array* due to broadcasting.  What you probably meant was something like:

```
F[i-1] + dx*(Z*sqrt(k*A**4 - k*x[i]**4))
```